# Json array result in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

How to get data like this in controller in using CodeIgniter?

```
{
  "price": [
    [
      1483275269000,
      972.948
    ],
    [
      1483361668000,
      1025.88
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've tried:

```
$invoices = $this->invoice_model->getAllData2(logged('company_id'));
$response['price'] = $invoices;
echo json_encode($response,TRUE);
```

I only get like this:

```
{"price":[{"date_issued":"2021-03-01","grand_total":"972.948"},{"date_issued":"2021-03-12","grand_total":"1025.88"}]}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped solving your problem.

Comment: Tips for posting here: (1) consider accepting the answer if it helped solving your problem; (2) do not beg for help; (3) word your questions so that readers know you will still take on the bulk of the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs just further processing to return it the way you like

```
$temp = [];
foreach($invoices as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {    
        switch($key2) {
            case 'date_issued':
                $temp[$key1][] = strtotime($value2);
            break;
            case 'grand_total':
                $temp[$key1][] = floatval($value2);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
$response['price'] = $temp;
echo json_encode($response,TRUE);
```

Comment: This looks good, but `$response` could do with some initialisation here.